# React Router not refreshing the page even though the url changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a clone of Whatsapp, and I am not able to rerender the page after a URL change. The backend I am using is firebase. The useEffect does not seem to render with the change of roomId.
Github link of this project: https://github.com/aditramdas/Chat-App/tree/main/chat-app-new/src

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Chat from "./Chat.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="app-body">
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/rooms/:roomId" component={<Chat />}>
              <Chat />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <Chat />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Chat.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./Chat.css";
import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { AttachFile } from "@material-ui/icons";
import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";
import MicIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mic";
import InsetEmoticonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/InsertEmoticon";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import db from "./firebase";

function Chat() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [photo, setphoto] = useState("");
  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      console.log("Change");
      db.collection("rooms")
        .doc(roomId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setRoomName(snapshot.data().name));
    }
  }, [roomId]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setphoto(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000));
  }, []);
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("You typed a message");
    setInput("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="chat">
      <div className="chat-header">
        <Avatar
          src={`https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/pixel-art/${photo}.svg`}
        />
        <div className="chat-headerInfo">
          <h2>{roomName}</h2>
          <p>Last Seen</p>
        </div>
        <div className="chat-headerRight">
          <IconButton>
            <SearchOutlined />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <AttachFile />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="chat-body">
        <p className="chat-message chatReceiver">
          <span className="sender">Adith Ramdas</span>
          Hello
          <span className="timestamp">12:30AM</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="chat-footer">
        <InsetEmoticonIcon />
        <form>
          <input
            value={input}
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type a message"
          />
          <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit">
            Send a message
          </button>
        </form>
        <MicIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Comment: What is the starting URL and what is the end one?

Comment: The URL changes when I click each chat. When I click the chat, the URL changes, but the name of the chat doesn't

Comment: You are rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component and have `react-router-dom@5.2.0` installed. Bump to *at least* `react-router-dom@5.3.3` to fix an issue that was introduced in `react@18` with the `StrictMode` component and RRD routers. See the marked duplicate for more details.